# An error has occured during report processing

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, msbi

I have few reports and while i tried to add the subscription i got the below pop-up error.

[image: Press this link for the error pop-up image]

Kindly suggest the possible solutions.Thanks in advance

Comment: A very small picture of a generic error message as displayed on a screen is of no use. You will need to provide more details before anyone can help.

Comment: Does this happen already in the SSRS dashboard when creating the subscription? I remember seeing something like that earlier when language and regional settings in firefox were not in the way SSRS wanted them to be... But this could of course be something totally different too.

Comment: Have you checked the SSRS log files for any SQL errors?